# PowerShell Savetofile cannot save with file extension

Tags: powershell

I have a below code to get the PDF attachments from the .eml files and save to same location

the code runs but when it saves it saves without an extension as .pdf.

am i missing something?

any help please?

```
$FileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Extract *.eml -recurse | Where-object {!$_.psIsContainer -eq $true} | ForEach-Object -Process {$_.FullName}
$MsgNames = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Extract *.eml -recurse | Where-object {!$_.psIsContainer -eq $true} | ForEach-Object -Process {$_.Name}
#Crawl through Files
for ($i=0; $i -lt $FileNames.Count; $i++) {
$emlFn  = $FileNames[$i]
$MsgName = $MsgNames[$i]
$adoDbStream = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Stream
$adoDbStream.Open()
$adoDbStream.LoadFromFile($emlFn)
$cdoMessage = New-Object -ComObject CDO.Message
$cdoMessage.DataSource.OpenObject($adoDbStream, "_Stream")
$Subject = $CdoMessage.Subject
foreach($attachment in $cdoMessage.Attachments){
$FILENAME = $CdoMessage.Attachments.Filename
$ATTFILENAME = ($Subject + $FILENAME)

  
 Write-Output $ATTFILENAME

$attachment.SaveToFile("$(Join-Path C:\Extract $ATTFILENAME )")




}

$adoDbStream.Close()
}
```

Comment: I would investigate existing properties behind "$CdoMessage.Attachments" . No full file name ?

Comment: "... it saves without an extension as .pdf" - how did you test this? If you're using Windows Explorer to inspect the files after: make sure you haven't configured the view settings to hide file extensions

Comment: You are a Legend @Civette!!. Just removed the "$CdoMessage" from the above and now can get the file extensions.  ````$FILENAME = $attachment. Filename````

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen nope nothing was hidden...basically it wasn't coming with file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this becomes the answer :)

```
...
foreach($attachment in $cdoMessage.Attachments){
$FILENAME = $Attachment.Filename
$ATTFILENAME = ($Subject + $FILENAME)
  
Write-Output $ATTFILENAME

$attachment.SaveToFile("$(Join-Path C:\Extract $ATTFILENAME )")
}
...
```